# com.github.nanchen2251:CompressHelper:1.0.6 gradle dependency is failing

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

The android gradle project that I started working has the dependency com.github.nanchen2251:CompressHelper:1.0.6. But whenever I try to build the project it failing with the following error.

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.github.nanchen2251:CompressHelper:1.0.6.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve com.github.nanchen2251:CompressHelper:1.0.6.
> > Could not get resource 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox/com/github/nanchen2251/CompressHelper/1.0.6/CompressHelper-1.0.6.pom'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox/com/github/nanchen2251/CompressHelper/1.0.6/CompressHelper-1.0.6.pom'.
> > Certificate for <mapbox.bintray.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.jfrog.io, jfrog.io]

How can we identify if the library is still available?

Comment: Check official website of the library or the repository where you found this library initially.
Check if the library is available on any other repositories like mavenCentral.

Comment: Not much info is available on the git page. Moreover, they have some Chinese texts/comments within the code. Using google translate got to know that it was built on top of another library.

Comment: check `build.gradle` and try dependency  `...CompressHelper:1.0.5` as it mentioned [here](https://github.com/nanchen2251/CompressHelper).